# Arquitectura por capas y Manejo de clases (no framework)

Tags: php, estructuras, arquitectura

## Actualizado

Tengo un problema de desbordamiento de memoria en una arquitectura por capas, el desarrollo ya lleva varios años y han tratado de optimizar algunas partes pero el principal problema radica en las Instancias de las clases en las sub-capas

lo enumero de la siguiente manera para que tengamos una idea general de como esta la estructura:

## Capa1

Archivo Index.php

```
require_once "control/class.Main.php"; #hacemos el require once a la libreria Main de nuestra APP
$WebAPP = new Class_MAIN();
$WebAPP->Main(); #llamamos a la Funcion Main
```

## Capa2

Archivo Main.php

```
class Class_MAIN {
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'control/config/config.externas.php'; #este archivo realiza un include de las librerias externas
        require_once 'control/config/config.genericas.php'; #este archivo realiza un include de las librerias genericas
        require_once 'control/config/config.modulos.php'; #este archivo realiza un include de las modulares
        //el archivo config.modulos.php se encarga de hacer include de otros archivo 
        //en este caso class.content.php y class.menu.php

        #Instanciamos las clases necesarias

        $this->CONTENTMANAGER  = new Class_ContentManager(); #el contenido a Mostrar por pantalla.

    }
    #llamada a la clase que genera el Display
    public function Main() {
        $this->CONTENTMANAGER->Gen_Display(); # Genera el Codigo html de la pagina.
    }
}
```

## Capa3

archivo class.content.php
en la capa 3 podemos ubicar la clase CONTENTMANAGER citada en la capa 2, esta inicializa clases que fueron incluidas(require_once) en la capa 2.
la funcion GetMenuSide levanta algunos archivos mediante require_once que en realidad son html.
como vemos en el contructor por primera ves vemos la clase Class_BDManager que es intanciada

```
    class Class_ContentManager{
        public function __construct() {
            #Llamamos a los archivos que se requieren para el funcionamiento de la pagina
            $this->MENUMANAGER    = new Class_MenuManager();
            $this->FORMMANAGER    = new Class_FormManager();
            $this->PROCESSMANAGER = new Class_ProcessManager();
            $this->MODALSMANAGER  = new Class_ModalManager();
            $this->DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
        }
        function GetMenuSide() {
            require_once "sources/tpl/navside/start.side.php";
            $this->MENUMANAGER->MenuSideManager();
            require_once "sources/tpl/navside/end.side.php";
        }
    }
```

## Capa4

archivo class.menu.php
    se puede decir que en esta capa esta la clase MenuSideManager citada en la capa 3 y que a su vez inicializa nuevamente clases $this->DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager(); que fueron incluidas en la capa 2

```
class Class_MenuManager{
        public function __construct() {
            $this->DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
        }
        function MenuSideManager(){
            #Consulta permisos del menu
        }
    }
```

si vemos $this->DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager(); se a Instaciado por algun motivo en 2 capas la 3 y la 4, y hasta donde comprendo el sistema hace lo mismo en la capa 5, 6, 7, 8; tambien observo que no solamente es una clase, digamos que esto ocurre con clases por bloques:

## Clases Externas

## Clases genericas

## Clases para generar Vistas(Listas Etc)

solo las clases Genericas realizan estas intancias de llamado, por cada Archivo de clase en la seccion de modulo que seria la capa 6:

```
$this->COOKIESMANAGER  = new Class_CookiesManager();
$this->CRIPMANAGER     = new Class_CripManager();
$this->DATEMANAGER     = new Class_DateManager();
$this->DBMANAGER       = new Class_BDManager();
$this->ERRORMANAGER    = new Class_ErrorManager();
$this->FILEMANAGER     = new Class_FileManager();
$this->HTTPDATAMANAGER = new Class_HTTPDataManager();
$this->LOGSMANAGER     = new Class_LogsManager();
$this->MEMORYMANAGER   = new Class_MemoryManager();
$this->URLMANAGER      = new Class_UrlManager();
$this->USERMANAGER     = new Class_UserManager();
$this->CRUDMANAGER     = new Class_CrudManager();# permisos
$this->SESSIONMANAGER  = new Class_SessionManager();
$this->EMAILMANAGER    = new Class_EmailManager();
$this->ORDERMANAGER    = new Class_OrderManager();
$this->VARMANAGER      = new Class_VarManager();
$this->FTPMANAGER      = new Class_FtpManager();
```

la parte de los require_once se realiza de forma dinamica con el siguiente script:

```
<?php
class Class_MAIN{
    protected $ObjClass;
    protected $ObjNameclass;
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'const/Constant.php';
        require_once 'class/ClassManager.php';
        $this->AUTOLOAD = new ClassManager();
        $this->ObjClass = [];
        $this->ObjClass = $this->AUTOLOAD->LoadClass($this->ObjClass);
        foreach ($this->ObjClass as $key => $Class) {
            require_once $Class;
        }
        #aqui se instanciaran solo  las clases necesarias
    }
    public function Main() {

    #aqui iran las funciones necesarias


    }
}
?>
```

## la idea principal o objetivo es:

heredar de alguna manera el instanciamiento de las clases mediante un objeto publico que pueda ser accesado desde cualquier de las sub-capas y hacer uso directo de las funciones que están en la clases genéricas,un ejemplo de consulta a base de dato seria algo asi:

```
#$this->ObjNameclass['DBManager'] puede ser la propiedad declara o objeto eredado

$this->$this->ObjNameclass['DBManager']->BDQuery(datos);
```

Sé que me dirán que mejor use una framework pero eso indicaría que debo realizar todo un desarrollo que ya lleva 6 años, y ademas muchos archivos a editar por cada capa, buscaría la manera de editar lo menos posible estos archivos. Busco una solución basada en esta misma arquitectura.

Estaré realizando otras actualizaciones con mas detalles implementando las respuestas de los compañeros.

Comment: veo un problema estas haciendo un require y estas validando si previamente las cargas

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario @JackNavaRow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, lo que tienes ES un framework, pero deberías establecer un punto de partida para la aplicación e ir cargando los módulos heredando la funcionalidad previa, yo empezaría por definir una clase general que las englobe a todas:

```
class APP {
    // aquí deberías incluir todas las propiedades como protegidas,
    // así únicamente una clase que herede de APP podrá obtener su
    // contenido y podría modificarlo (todas las clases deberían
    // heredar de APP, por lo que no tendrías inconvenientes de 
    // acceso, pero lo restringes a tu framework)
    protected CONTENTMANAGER;
    protected MENUMANAGER;
    protected FORMMANAGER;
    protected PROCESSMANAGER;
    protected MODALSMANAGER;
    protected DBMANAGER;

    public function  __construct() {
        // requerir sólo lo necesario en cada caso
        require_once 'control/config/config.externas.php';
        require_once 'control/config/config.genericas.php';
        require_once 'control/config/config.modulos.php';

        // no instanciar nada aquí

    }
}
```

Y luego, hacer que cada parte del sistema herede de la base del mismo:

```
class Class_MAIN extends APP {
    public function __construct(){
        // Llamar al constructor padre para que genere los require
        parent::__construct();

        $this->CONTENTMANAGER  = new Class_ContentManager();
    }

    public function Main(){
        $this->CONTENTMANAGER->Gen_Display($USERLoged, $DTACheck);
    }
}
```

Si necesitas cargar módulos o inicializar clases antes de utilizar alguna parte del sistema, lo que tienes que hacer es cargar el constructor de la clase de la que se extiende, en este caso sería `APP` y luego, cargar los módulos o instanciar las propiedades:

```
class Class_ContentManager extends APP {
    public function __construct() {
        // Llamar al constructor padre para que genere los require
        parent::__construct();

        // Poblar las propiedades requeridas para el funcionamiento de la página
        $this->MENUMANAGER    = new Class_MenuManager();
        $this->FORMMANAGER    = new Class_FormManager();
        $this->PROCESSMANAGER = new Class_ProcessManager();
        $this->MODALSMANAGER  = new Class_ModalManager();
        $this->DBMANAGER      = new Class_BDManager();
    }

    function GetMenuSide() {
            require_once "sources/tpl/navside/start.side.php";
            $this->MENUMANAGER->MenuSideManager();
            require_once "sources/tpl/navside/end.side.php";
    }
}
```

De esta manera, evitas que se solicite e instancie dos veces una misma clase y puedes utilizarlas en todas las capas subsiguientes.

**Edición:**

Si lo que quieres es que cierta funcionalidad se encuentre disponible para todas las clases que heredan de `APP`, sólo tienes que incluir esa funcionalidad en `APP`, por ejemplo, si quieres tener ya instanciada la funcionalidad de base de datos, la clase `APP` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
class APP {
    // aquí deberías incluir todas las propiedades como protegidas,
    // así únicamente una clase que herede de APP podrá obtener su
    // contenido y podría modificarlo (todas las clases deberían
    // heredar de APP, por lo que no tendrías inconvenientes de 
    // acceso, pero lo restringes a tu framework)
    protected CONTENTMANAGER;
    protected MENUMANAGER;
    protected FORMMANAGER;
    protected PROCESSMANAGER;
    protected MODALSMANAGER;
    protected DBMANAGER;

    public function  __construct() {
        // requerir sólo lo necesario en cada caso
        require_once 'control/config/config.externas.php';
        require_once 'control/config/config.genericas.php';
        require_once 'control/config/config.modulos.php';

        // instanciar sólo lo necesario
        $this->DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
    }
}
```

Y, posteriormente, eliminar todas las instanciaciones en los constructores de `$this->DBMANAGER` para evitar que se recarguen en cada capa.

**Actualización - Solución Final**

Viendo detalladamente tu código y analizando lo que hace y tus explicaciones, creo que lo que necesitas es un código como el siguiente:

```
// los objetos creados, serán globales
$Objects = [];

// clase que maneja las clases ;)
class ClassManager{

    // Función de carga de clases, es estática para evitar tener que 
    // instanciar el manejador de clases, agrega la clase al arreglo
    // de objetos globales y retorna la instancia generada
    public static function LoadClass($clase, $nueva_instancia = false){
        // Obtengo los objetos globales
        global $Objects;

        // si no existe el objeto de esta clase o existe pero
        // se requiere una nueva instancia
        if(!isset($Objects[$clase]) || 
           (isset($Objects[$clase]) && $nueva_instancia == true)) {

            // cargo el archivo
            require_once "class/$clase.php";

            // instancio
            $instancia = new $clase();

            // agrego la instancia al arreglo de objetos globales
            $Objects[$clase] = $instancia;
        } else {
            // sino, obtengo la instancia del arreglo de objetos globales
            $instancia = $Objects[$clase];
        }

        // y retorno la instancia
        return $instancia;
    }
}
```

lo que tendrás que hacer luego es, en cualquier lugar de tu código que necesites instanciar (u obtener una instancia, dependiendo del caso) será:

```
ClassManager::LoadClass('DBManager')->BDQuery(datos);
```

en caso de necesitar que se recargue la instancia, deberías poner en true el segundo parámetro de LoadClass:

```
ClassManager::LoadClass('ErrorManager', true)->ShowError('Lo que sea');
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias se ve interesante y sencillo pero el problema es " // Poblar las propiedades requeridas para el funcionamiento de la página" deseo simplificar esto a "poblar necesidades Externas","poblar necesidades Genéricas","poblar necesidades MODULOS", para evitar la recursividad de  `$this->DBMANAGER      = new Class_BDManager();` en cada Clase o capa

Comment: Bien, entonces deberías separar tu estructura en tres partes: externos, genericos y modulos, pero todos heredando de APP.

Comment: es fácil decirlo cuando no tienes 300 archivos que actualizar... y algunos con 2000 o mas lineas de codigo...

Comment: No necesitas instanciar todo el tiempo y en cada capa usando `$this->DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager()`, sólo lo haces en el constructor de APP

Comment: ok dejame revisar lo que dices y te comento.

Comment: Revisa la edición de la respuesta.

Comment: pregunta `parent::__construct();` no provocaria aumento en el consumo de memoria tal cual lo hace instancias las clases en cada sub clase???

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67548/discussion-between-andres-morales-and-francisco-nunez).

Comment: Gracias por la cooperaciones pero esto no apoya la intanciacion dinámica en sub-capas. saludos

Comment: Realice una actualización de la Pregunta y actualice los detalles en general para que tengas una idea aproximada de lo que se esta haciendo... y del objetivo en concreto

Comment: Bien, creo que entendí qué es lo que necesitabas, es una mezcla del patrón singleton con el patrón factory.

Comment: si es correcto y ya tengo unos avances en otro post

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/112021/46896

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que hacer los include y evitar que se incluyan a si mismas las clases puedes usar `class_exists` antes de definir la clase en cada archivo de definición de clase de esa forma aun que el método llame a al include la clase no se definirá de nuevo.

```
if (! class_exists('MyClass')) {

    class MyClass {

    }

}
```

Para evitar definir de nuevo la misma variable y tener acceso a ella.

```
protected static DBMANAGER = null;
```

o

```
public static DBMANAGER = null;
```

y usarlo asi:

```
public function __construct() {

    if (! self::DBMANAGER instanceof Class_BDManager) {
        self::DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
    }
}
```

Para instanciar DBMANAGER en cualquier parte puedes hacer publica la propiedad y hacer:

```
if (! Class_MenuManager::DBMANAGER instanceof Class_BDManager) {
   Class_MenuManager::DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
}
```

ó

Puedes hacer la propiedad protected y hacer un metodo setter publico:

```
public static setDbManager (Class_BDManager $db) {

    if (! Class_MenuManager::DBMANAGER instanceof Class_BDManager) {
       Class_MenuManager::DBMANAGER = $db;
    }

}
```

ó

```
public static setDbManager () {

    if (! Class_MenuManager::DBMANAGER instanceof Class_BDManager) {
       Class_MenuManager::DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
    }

}
```

Tus definiciones de clase quedarían de la siguiente forma:

```
if (! class_exists('Class_MenuManager') ) {

    class Class_MenuManager{

        private static DBMANAGER = null;

        public function __construct() {

        }

        function MenuSideManager(){
            #Consulta permisos del menu
        }

        public static setDbManager () {

            if (! self::DBMANAGER instanceof Class_BDManager) {
                self::DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager();
            }

        }

         public static getDbManager () {

            self::setDbManager();
            return self::DBMANAGER;
        }

    }
}
```

para obtener `DBMANAGER` desde cualquier lugar `$db = Class_MenuManager::getDbManager();` siempre obtendrás el mismo objeto. pero como vez lo quite del constructor para que no este definido si no lo vaz a usar y `getDbManager` se asegura de definirlo antes de usarlo por lo que no tendrás problema

Comment: no entiendo tu respuesta.

Comment: segun lo que entiendo me indicas como evitar definir multiples veces una clase, pero lo que yo busco no es solamente eso, es que si ya esta definida 4 capas antes como puedo acceder a ellas ten en cuenta que no es solo una clase pueden ser 5, 6, 7 clases de uso genérico...

Comment: No se si he entendido bien la pregunta pero si lo que necesitas es que no se definan de nuevo las propiedades puedes hacer las mismas estatiticas. revisa la edicion

Comment: Espero haber entendido bien el problema. Si no po rfavor extiende un poco la explicación y si puedes incluir los errores que obtienes mejor. Gracias

Comment: ok ahora si comprendo mejor tu ejemplo, pero digamos que en la capa 2 instancie la clase `Class_BDManager` en la capa 3 y 4 no lo hice, ya que no fue necesario su uso, pero en la capa 5 si la voy a necesitar usar... como quedaría en ese caso tu ejemplo.

Comment: la otro seria si es posible convertir estoen un objeto:
        `self::DBMANAGER = new Class_BDManager()`

Comment: según las ultimas actualizaciones que veo con lo del setter publico, esto me ayudaría evitar la redundancia y el desbordamiento de memoria??

Comment: No puedo decirte si soluciona tu problema de memoria por completo pero si que reducirá el uso de la misma.

Comment: solo me queda una pregunta, este codigo `public static DBMANAGER = null;` que entiendo que se refiere a publicar la clase si lo hago en la clase main como quedaría, lo puedo hacer en el constructor mediante un archivo llamado con un requiered? ya que debo hacer esto como con 15 clases creo.

Comment: la idea principal es hacerlo de una manera que sea facil de darle mantenimiento en un futuro al agregar mas clases etc..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67536/discussion-between-sergio-cauich-and-francisco-nunez).