# acceder a Instancias almacenadas en un objeto en sub capas

Tags: php, estructuras, patrones-de-diseño

tengo un problema pequeñísimo:

declare una clase Main con propiedad de la siguiente manera, para que cargue los archivos require_once de forma dinamica, dependiendo de las clases que tenga almacenadas en alguna carpetas, y funciona correctamente, tambien se encarga de llamar a una funcion en otro archivo que se encarga de instanciar las clases y las almacena en una propiedad de tipo objeto:

```
<?php
class Class_MAIN{
    public $ObjClass;
    public $ObjClassInst;
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'const/Constant.php';
        require_once 'class/ClassManager.php';
        $this->AUTOLOAD = new ClassManager();
        $this->ObjClass = [];
        $this->ObjClass = $this->AUTOLOAD->LoadClass($this->ObjClass);
        foreach ($this->ObjClass as $key => $Class) {
            require_once $Class;
        }
        $this->ObjClassInst = [];
        $this->ObjClassInst = $this->AUTOLOAD->ClassPack($this->ObjClassInst);
    }
    public function Main() {
        $this->ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA3MANAGER'] ->pruebacapa3();
    }
}
?>
```

esto funciona correcto y me genera un objeto en el indice de clases generic me guarda cada Clase Instanciada:

```
array(1) { 
    ["Generic"]=> array(3) { 
        ["CAPA5MANAGER"]=> object(Class_Capa5Manager)#3 (0) { } 
        ["CAPA4MANAGER"]=> object(Class_Capa4Manager)#4 (0) { } 
        ["CAPA3MANAGER"]=> object(Class_Capa3Manager)#5 (0) { } 
    } 
}
```

La Libreria que me genera este objeto, que hace los require_once de cada clase segun el directorio y que a su vez guarda las intancias en el objeto ClassManager Siguiente:

```
<?php
class ClassManager {
    public function LoadClassExternal(&$ObjClass) {
        $External = scandir(EXTCLASS, 1); # Directorio de archivos
        foreach ($External as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
                #require_once EXTCLASS.''.
                $ObjClass[$name] = EXTCLASS . $name;
            } elseif(strpos($name, 'phpMailer') !== false) {
                $ObjClass[$name] = EXTCLASS . $name .'/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            } elseif(strpos($name, 'html2pdf') !== false) {
                $ObjClass[$name] = EXTCLASS . $name .'/html2pdf.class.php';
            } elseif(strpos($name, 'fpdf') !== false) {
                $ObjClass[$name] = EXTCLASS . $name .'/fpdf.php';
            }
        }
        return $ObjClass;
    }
    public function LoadClassGeneric(&$ObjClass) {
        $Generic = scandir(GENCLASS, 1); # Directorio de archivos
        foreach ($Generic as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
                $ObjClass[$name] = GENCLASS . $name;
            }
        }
        return $ObjClass;
    }
    public function LoadClassCRON(&$ObjClass) {
        $Cron = scandir(CRONCLASS, 1); # Directorio de archivos
        foreach ($Cron as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
                $ObjClass[$name] = CRONCLASS . $name;
            }
        }
        return $ObjClass;
    }
    public function LoadClassMVC(&$ObjClass) {
        $MVC = scandir(MVCCLASS, 1); # Directorio de archivos
        foreach ($MVC as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
                $ObjClass[$name] = MVCCLASS . $name;
            }
        }
        return $ObjClass;
    }
    public function LoadClassCORE(&$ObjClass) {
        $CoreD = scandir(CORECLASS, 1); # Directorio de archivos
        foreach ($CoreD as $key => $nameD) {
            if (strpos($nameD, 'doc') !== false) {
                $CoreF = scandir(CORECLASS.$nameD.'/', 1); # Directorio de archivos
                foreach ($CoreF as $key => $nameF) {
                    if (strpos($nameF, 'doc') !== false) {
                        $ObjClass[$nameF] = CORECLASS.$nameD.'/' . $nameF;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strpos($nameD, 'form') !== false) {
                $CoreF = scandir(CORECLASS.$nameD.'/', 1); # Directorio de archivos
                foreach ($CoreF as $key => $nameF) {
                    if (strpos($nameF, 'form') !== false) {
                        $ObjClass[$nameF] = CORECLASS.$nameD.'/' . $nameF;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strpos($nameD, 'list') !== false) {
                $CoreF = scandir(CORECLASS.$nameD.'/', 1); # Directorio de archivos
                foreach ($CoreF as $key => $nameF) {
                    if (strpos($nameF, 'list') !== false) {
                        $ObjClass[$nameF] = CORECLASS.$nameD.'/' . $nameF;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strpos($nameD, 'modal') !== false) {
                $CoreF = scandir(CORECLASS.$nameD.'/', 1); # Directorio de archivos
                foreach ($CoreF as $key => $nameF) {
                    if (strpos($nameF, 'modal') !== false) {
                        $ObjClass[$nameF] = CORECLASS.$nameD.'/' . $nameF;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strpos($nameD, 'not') !== false) {
                $CoreF = scandir(CORECLASS.$nameD.'/', 1); # Directorio de archivos
                foreach ($CoreF as $key => $nameF) {
                    if (strpos($nameF, 'not') !== false) {
                        $ObjClass[$nameF] = CORECLASS.$nameD.'/' . $nameF;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strpos($nameD, 'process') !== false) {
                $CoreF = scandir(CORECLASS.$nameD.'/', 1); # Directorio de archivos
                foreach ($CoreF as $key => $nameF) {
                    if (strpos($nameF, 'process') !== false) {
                        $ObjClass[$nameF] = CORECLASS.$nameD.'/' . $nameF;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $ObjClass;
    }
    public function LoadClass(&$ObjClass) {
        #require files
        $this->LoadClassExternal($ObjClass);
        $this->LoadClassGeneric($ObjClass);
        $this->LoadClassCRON($ObjClass);
        $this->LoadClassMVC($ObjClass);
        $this->LoadClassCORE($ObjClass);
        return $ObjClass;
    }
    public function ClassPackExternal(&$ObjClassInst) {
        return $ObjClassInst;
    }
    #Esta Seccion es la que instancia las Clases
    public function ClassPackGeneric(&$ObjClassInst) {
        $Generic = scandir(GENCLASS, 1); # Directorio de archivos
        foreach ($Generic as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
                $name=preg_replace('#\.php#', '', $name);
                $names=explode(".", $name);
                foreach ($names as $key => $namesr) {
                    $names[$key]=ucfirst(strtolower($namesr));
                }
                $name=implode('_', $names);
                $NamesClass = $name.'Manager';
                $InstanceClass = strtoupper(preg_replace('#\Class_#', '', $NamesClass));
                #$ObjClassInst['Generic'][$InstanceClass] = $NamesClass;
                $ObjClassInst['Generic'][$InstanceClass] = $this->$InstanceClass= new $NamesClass();
            }
        }
        return $ObjClassInst;
    }
    public function ClassPackCRON(&$ObjClassInst) {
        return $ObjClassInst;
    }
    public function ClassPackMVC(&$ObjClassInst) {
        return $ObjClassInst;
    }
    public function ClassPackCORE(&$ObjClassInst) {
        return $ObjClassInst;
    }
    public function ClassPack(&$ObjClassInst){
        #require files
        $this->ClassPackExternal($ObjClassInst);
        $this->ClassPackGeneric($ObjClassInst);
        $this->ClassPackCRON($ObjClassInst);
        $this->ClassPackMVC($ObjClassInst);
        $this->ClassPackCORE($ObjClassInst);
        return $ObjClassInst;
    }
}
?>
```

hasta que llego a las capa 4 y 5:

archivos por separados:

```
<?php
    class Class_Capa3Manager {
        function pruebacapa3(){
            $this->ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA4MANAGER'] ->pruebacapa4();
        }
    }
?>
```

archivos por separados:

```
<?php
    class Class_Capa4Manager {
        function pruebacapa4(){
            $this->ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA5MANAGER'] ->pruebacapa5();
        }
    }
?>
```

archivos por separados:

```
<?php
    class Class_Capa5Manager {
        function pruebacapa5(){
            echo 'lo Logre';
        }
    }
?>
```

Como debo declarar la Propiedad: `public $ObjClassInst;` para que este accesible en cualquier de las capas, **sin necesidad de pasarla como un parámetro, sin utilizar extend [ClassName] y poder llamarla tal cual esta en la capa 3 y 4 **.

```
Notice: Undefined property: Class_Capa3Manager::$ObjClassInst in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class\classgen\class.capa3.php on line 4

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function pruebacapa4() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class\classgen\class.capa3.php:4 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class.Main.php(18): Class_Capa3Manager->pruebacapa3() #1
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\index.php(15): Class_MAIN->Main() #2 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t2\class\classgen\class.capa3.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes acceder primero a `Generic` y los () no son necesarios ya que es un el objeto al parecer ya esta instanciado:

```
$this->ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA5MANAGER'] ->pruebacapa5;
```

Respecto a tu nuevo error `ObjClassInst` es una propiedad de `Class_MAIN` por ello no puedes acceder con `$this` en el otra clase pero puedes hacer statica la propiedad y acceder de esta forma:

```
<?php

<?php
class Class_MAIN{
    public $ObjClass;
    public static $ObjClassInst;
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'const/Constant.php';
        require_once 'class/ClassManager.php';
        $this->AUTOLOAD = new ClassManager();
        $this->ObjClass = [];
        $this->ObjClass = $this->AUTOLOAD->LoadClass($this->ObjClass);
        foreach ($this->ObjClass as $key => $Class) {
            require_once $Class;
        }
        self::$ObjClassInst = [];
        self::$ObjClassInst = $this->AUTOLOAD->ClassPack($this->ObjClassInst);
    }
    public function Main() {
        self::$ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA3MANAGER'] ->pruebacapa3();
    }
}

class Class_Capa3Manager {
    function pruebacapa4(){
        Class_MAIN::$ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA4MANAGER']->pruebacapa4();
    }
}


class Class_Capa4Manager {
    function pruebacapa4(){
        Class_MAIN::$ObjClassInst['Generic']['CAPA5MANAGER']->pruebacapa5();
    }
}

class Class_Capa5Manager {
    function pruebacapa5(){
        echo "Lo lograste";
    }
}
```

**Edicion**

Esta forma ocupara menos recursos aun.

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($className)
{

  $class = array (

    'Class_MAIN' => '/var/www/clases/Class_DateManager.php',
    'Class_DateManager' => '/var/www/clases/Class_DateManager.php',
    'Otro' => '/var/www/otro.php',
    'Class_Capa3Manager' => '/var/www/clases/Class_Capa3Manager.php',
    'Class_Capa4Manager' => '/var/www/clases/Class_Capa4Manager.php',
    'Class_Capa5Manager' => '/var/www/clases/Class_Capa5Manager.php',
    /*
      todos los archivos de clase.
    */
  );

  if (isset($class[$className]) && file_exists($class[$className]))
    require_once $class[$className];
});



class Class_MAIN{
    public $ObjClass;
    private static $ObjClassInst = array();
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'const/Constant.php';
        require_once 'class/ClassManager.php';

        foreach ($this->ObjClass as $key => $Class) {
            require_once $Class;
        }
        self::$ObjClassInst = [];

    }
    public function Main() {
        Class_MAIN::getObject('Class_Capa3Manager')->pruebacapa3();
    }

    public static function getObject($className) {

        if (! isset(self::$ObjClassInst[$objectName]) ||  ! self::$ObjClassInst[$objectName] instanceof $className) {

          return self::$ObjClassInst[$objectName] = new $className();
        }
    }

    public static function clearObject($className) {

        if (isset(self::$ObjClassInst[$objectName])) {

          unset(self::$ObjClassInst[$objectName]);
        }
    }
}

class Class_Capa3Manager {
    function pruebacapa4(){
        Class_MAIN::getObject('Class_Capa4Manager')->pruebacapa4();
    }
}


class Class_Capa4Manager {
    function pruebacapa4(){
        Class_MAIN::getObject('Class_Capa5Manager')->pruebacapa5();
    }
}

class Class_Capa5Manager {
    function pruebacapa5(){
        echo "Lo lograste";
    }
}
```

El auto load va e un archivo aparte que se incluye en el index.php o en el index.php directamente el caso . Si no todas las peticiones ingresan por el index.php debes incluir al autoload al principio del archivo principal.

Comment: si claro esto ya esta listo... hare una actualizacion tengo otro error.

Comment: si correcto ya lo agregue.

Comment: Edite la respuesta para ver si con ello puedes solucionar tu otro error

Comment: ya lo estoy verificando ... pero como serial el salto de la capa 3 a la 4 y de la 4 a la 5???

Comment: y que opinas de esta estructura???

Comment: Es parecida a lo que te comenté en el otro post solo que ahí te desea que lo hicieras con métodos de acceso estáticos. Y no había comprendido que querías definir todos en un array en la clase principal. Ahí entendí que querías llamarlos como los necesitaras.

Comment: es correcto con esta estructura puedo llamar a una funcion desde cualquier lugar ... y cualquier capa, y asi no tengo que redefinir ninguna de las clases, con esto supongo que ahorrare mucha memoria del sistema, el proximo paso sera aprender e implementar los namespace.

Comment: Y que pex no me gane los 200 puntos ? jejeje

Comment: Ahora que entendí el problema mañana te voy a poner una solución con autoload y setter y getter static que definan el objeto solo cuando lo necesites.

Comment: Revisa la edición talvez te sirva.

Comment: si pero los asigne antes ... por hay te paso unos puntos depsues...

Comment: Bueno ya ni modo. Otro día sera. Mañana te pongo un ejemplo con namespaces.

Comment: Existira alguna manera de simplificar: `Class_MAIN::$ObjClassInst` pense en meter en los contruct algo como `$ClassObj = &Class_MAIN::$ObjClassInst;`

Comment: Si revisa la sección edición en el código de ejemplo, el autoload no es necesario. la idea es usar funciones estáticas. para acceder a la propiedad estática. esto facilitara el acceso a la propiedad.