# Existencia de estándar para arquitectura PHP por módulos interconectables

Tags: php, diseño, patrones-de-diseño, arquitectura

En el desarrollo de una aplicación llegue a la conclusión de que debía implementar una arquitectura muy dinámica con características de interconexión para alcanzar el objetivo.

A dicha arquitectura se le dio Respuesta en: [acceder a Instancias almacenadas en un objeto en sub capas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112028/46896).

Ahora tengo una inquietud: ¿existe algún estándar documentado (NO Framework) que haga exactamente lo que se explica en la respuesta, ya que he estado buscando en Google y no lo consigo.

He leído que existen  PSR-0, PSR-1, PSR-2 y PSR-4, pero no he profundizado en su uso.

Comment: no son métodos estáticos, son métodos públicos, la pregunta es esta: ¿existe algún estándar documentado (NO Framework) que haga exactamente lo que se explica en la respuesta, ya que he estado buscando en Google y no lo consigo.? no puedo darte un ejemplo con dos lineas por eso agregue el Link de la referencia. si vez te llevara al código y lo que se busca es un standar semejante al código...

Comment: leí tu pregunta pero, como comenté recién, creo que podrías aclarar un poco qué es "*lo que se explica en la respuesta*". También leí tu otra pregunta y su respuesta aceptada, y creo que hay más de 1 concepto en juego. Además, creo que obtendrías mejores respuestas si no hubiese que leer tooooda esa pregunta y la respuesta para entender de qué estás hablando. ¿Podrás resumir dando algún indicio de qué estás hablando sin que haya que leer la otra publicación?

Comment: no se resumir un ejemplo de la otra pregunta y su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Respuesta Corta**: Si, existe.

**Respuesta Larga**:

Hay un par de patrones de diseño que pueden encajar en tu post anterior, dependiendo en realidad del nivel de abstracción de la misma.

Me parece que particularmente te refieres al patrón de diseño **Fábrica Abstracta** en donde tu clase principal entrega una interfaz para crear familias de objectos con estructuras similares (por lo menos en la estructura inicial). Aunque es cierto que todo está contenido en solo objecto, como he mencionado antes, todo depende del nivel de abstracción del observador pues al final del día obtienes diferentes instancias de otros objetos.

También cae dentro de la definición del patrón de **Fábrica** regular pues se podría decir que las subclases son quienes deciden que se va a crear por medio de un constructor alternativo.

Como recomendación, [Sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) tiene una excelente documentación sobre los patrones y antipatrones de diseño.

Por último, es complicado entender a que te refieres con tu pregunta pues hay muchos niveles de abstracción en el ejemplo y todo está abierto a la interpretación personal. Sugiero desambiguar que buscas exactamente si esto no ha respondido a la pregunta principal.

Comment: tienes razón al hacer una verificación de la pagina que me indicas parece ser que el diseño que presente es una mescla de varios diseños, he logrado ver: Abstract Factory, Factory Method, Singleton la pregunta seria si es correcto mesclarar, aun no tengo claro la definición de abstracción al 100%

Comment: o en tal caso de ser correcto si se puede elevar esto a un standar.

Comment: No hay problema con mezclar patrones de diseño, es normal mezclarlos en diferentes niveles de abstracción pero puedes complicar las cosas para otros programadores si no respetas el **principio de responsabilidad única** y ellos tienen que mantener tu código después.  

Si tus métodos y funciones hacen una sola cosa, su contenido explicará como se hace esa cosa. El contenido, las clases o medios pueden entonces estar sujetos a otro patrón de diseño.

Comment: si se respeta, cada clase/funcion(método) tiene en principio ejecutar una acción en concreta, ya sea que funcione como Controlador, Modelo o Vista, el detalle es que en un punto del desarrollo algunas cosas se vuelven tan repetitivas al desarrollar un backend de administración que sale mucho mejor tener funciones(Métodos) genéricos que puedas llamar desde cualquier ámbito y pesarlas tus parámetros para que te devuelva los resultados deseados. entonces terminas recurriendo a un patrón de diseño Dinámico, pero si no recurres a un framework terminas haciéndote el propio, mezclando otros patrones.

Comment: gracias aunque tarde ya se esta implementando en https://github.com/arcanisgk/Last-Hammer